# SVG image at full viewport

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have this kind of twisted bit of SVG that draws an image of Europe.  It's the result of a lot of unsavoury acts.  I'm not very good with SVG, either...

[p27.eu](https://www.p27.eu/index.html)

In its essentials, the code is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 <!-- compute the image dimensions, proposed code -->
 var w = window;
 var d = document;
 var e = d.documentElement;
 var g = e.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
 var x = w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth;
 var y = w.innerHeight|| e.clientHeight|| g.clientHeight;
 var eurlen = Math.min(x, y);
 <!-- end proposed code -->
</script>
<svg
   id="europe-svg"
   display: block
   align: xMidYMid
   width="300%"
   height="300%">
  <g
 id="layer1"
 transform="translate(-107.76319,-174.21562)">
<path>...</path>  <!-- one of these for each country -->
<rect
   style="opacity:1;fill:none;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none;stroke-width:8.37237263;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1;display:inline"
   id="rect10148"
   width="452.38409"
   height="447.94937"
   x="106.52205"
   y="174.79648" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

I want the image to display full frame.  I can compute the lengths I want (see proposed code, above).

But I'm having trouble getting this nightmarish abomination to scale to the viewport size.  First, this is because I'm not clear how to insert the javascript variable value into the svg height/width and the (at the end) rect height/width.  But also because when I modify those values manually the image doesn't respond at all in a way that is making sense to me.

Any suggestions, besides avoiding machine-generated SVG that was later modified by hand and inherited?

Comment: view-box ? It's easier if you define the view-box for the image. Then you can scale it with using css in the "wrapper" html element.

Comment: Adding it as a background is the easier way... Or do something like `svg id="europe-svg" viewBox="0 0 454 449" width="100vw" height="100vh"` (I'd suggest also to re-generate the svg from some graphic editor, like InkScape)

Answer (score 0):

There are just a couple steps you need to make:

Make the container full width and height, make the svg full width and height too, here's the CSS:

```
#europe {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
svg {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

Then, remove the width and height attributes from svg element, add a `viewBox` attribute instead, match it to your contents of svg (I'm not sure about your drawings' size, put something like `viewBox="0 0 400 400"` to start). That will get you started

Oh, and remove the margin from body:

```
body {
   margin: 0
}
```